# How to clear effect of a click button using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am doing something as shown bellow:

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $('<div></div>').appendTo('body');
});
```

It appends the division again and again when I click it, but what I want is when I click other button then there should be no effect of "btn1" means I want to clear the effect of first button after I click the second one.

How I can do this?

Comment: you shoud give some class to the div you append

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not add a class to the div that `btn1` adds:

```
$("#btn1").click(function() {
    $("<div class='new-div'></div>").appendTo('body');
});
```

Then you second button can remove it like so -

```
$("#btn2").click(function() {
    $(".new-div").remove();
});
```

Comment: Thanks! simplest answer is this. I was confused due to huge part of html I was appending.

Answer (score 2):

When you click first button it append's div tag into body

```
$("#btn1").click(function(){
    $('div').appendTo('body');
});
```

then when you click second button it remove the div tag from the body and clears the previous one

```
$("#btn2").click(function(){
    $('body').children("div").remove();
});
```

Comment: How about putting a little more effort into your answers? Code formatting? Some explanations perhaps...

Comment: thnks for ur feed back

Answer (score 1):

Well the simplest thing would be a flag:

```
var btn_is_active = true; // set flag's initial state

$( "#btn1" ).click( function(){
    if ( btn_is_active ){ // only perform action if boolean is true
      $( "<div></div>" ).appendTo( "body" );
    }
});


$( "#btn2" ).click( function(){
    // toggle the boolean value
    btn_is_active = !btn_is_active;
});
```

In the above example, `#btn2` controls the flag; Each time `#btn2` is clicked, the `btn_is_active` boolean is toggled from true to false and therefore enables/disables the functionality of `#btn1`.

---

In order to clear whatever action `#btn1` has already done, you'll have to be able to track all the `'<div></div>'` elements that were added. For this you might want to give them a class attribute and then `#btn2` could remove all the elements with that class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

i guess you want to disable the event of `#btn1` on first click

`$('#btn1").unbind('click');`

this will clear the registered click event with that button

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/click/ says about `.click`: "This method is a shortcut for `.on( "click", handler )`". So you'll need `.off` (http://api.jquery.com/off/) to clear the event handler.